# How to wait for webfonts to load?

Tags: javascript, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

I have a canvas element that uses webfonts. Even if I use jquery's onload method `($(function () {});)`, it seems that the fonts can still be unavailable when onload is run--at times my canvas renders no text, and at other times it works just fine.

Anyway I can pass some sort of callback to google webfonts to run after all the fonts have loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you embed the fonts through the "WebFont Loader" (used by Google and Typekit), you can subscribe to the `active` event. It will be fired once all fonts have been loaded.

Have a look at the docs: https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader#Events

Answer (score -4):

Try using the window load listener. It will fire after graphics, css, webfonts etc. are loaded.

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

> Run a function when the page is fully loaded including graphics.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    //do something
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kwLf9/1/